QOS policy for setting DSCP EF not working, Windows 10 Home
For an application in windows 10, it sends out UDP data.
I want to add a policy which adds DSCP EF tag to all the UDP packets going to a specific subnet (for any application).
At first gpedit was not present so I added it using this guide
After that, I added a policy through gpedit, as mentioned here
It was not working. Captured packet through Wireshark showed DSCP bit as 0x00
Tried all the steps mentioned here, here, here
Still not able to achieve it. Can anyone please help me?
Note: I don't have domain network profile.
OS: Windows 10 Home 22H2
